# Is there a way to turn back to windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

My case: I have bought the laptop with Windows10 (licensed product) on board and then by fault downloaded Windows 8(not licensed)

And now I would like to turn back to Windows 10

I heard that if you bought the laptop with licensed windows, so in future you can get your windows back by your laptop number... Something like this.

Question is: Is it true? If yes, how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @dsstorefile1 what is it recovery partition? How I can check it?

Comment: Open Disk Management and inspect your drive. The presence of the recovery partition allows for full reset to factory defaults. But even if it's not there you can install Windows 10 at any time - ignore the request for serial - because the license is still there and it activates fine. The only caveat with installing from scratch instead of reset is that you may need to install additional drivers.

Comment: What laptop is it? Do you have an idea of the version of windows as in 10home, 10pro? You can include a screenshot of the explorer menu for my computer to tell how many partitions you have

Comment: Your laptop manufacturer should provide recovery media.

Comment: if your computer has Windows 10 preinstalled then the key was integrated in BIOS. You just need to reinstall Windows and it'll automatically activate itself

Answer (score 3):

If there is a recovery partition you'll be able to reset the PC to factory default.
1. Click settings --> change PC settings 
2. Click Recovery and recovery then --> recovery 
3. Look for remove everything and reinstall windows, -->click get started and follow the onscreen steps

Make sure to backup your data as everything will be gone. When you get an option to wipe whole disk go for it.

Another option, 
Once you determine the preloaded windows that came with your PC, (you can find it from the manufacturer website) get a similar free version of the same windows and install, windows will automatically activate the device once it recognizes the edition as the factory edition.

Usually too the machine comes with the windows license key and could help you reactive after installing but if it wasn't included then the above methods should help.

If these 2 does not work then I guess you should contact the support

Comment: As Windows 10 is wiped and Windows 8 is installed the **settings --> change PC settings --> Recovery** option will not be available.

Comment: I think it'll be as that option is available for all windows 8 os

Comment: **settings --> change PC settings --> Recovery** will recover Windows 8 I believe rather than the factory set recovery.

Answer (score 0):

With any shop bought computer, as highlighted by Clement, the usual best order of methods would be option 1 below.  If that is not possible or you choose not to you can go for option 2 below.

1. **Reinstall Windows from Recovery**
   As you wiped your computer and installed Windows 8, you will need to follow your computer manufacturers instructions on recovery of Windows 10, (either switching off your computer and pressing a certain button after switch on **or** using a recovery disk)  see the instructions which came with your computer or find out from your computer manufacturer's support team.  If you have to use a recovery disk and you don't have one, you can either obtain one from the computer manufacturer or resort to option 2.
2. **Reinstall using a fresh download of Windows 10 [free from Microsoft themselves.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10)**
   **You will need a blank DVD or USB flash drive**.
   How this is to be done once you have the download sorted will depend on whether you have a license key or not **or** if your original copy of Windows 10 was activated or not.  I would assume that the manufacturer would have activated your copy but I am not sure as I have never bought a shop bought Windows 10 computer.  As you say you downloaded Windows 8 (unlicensed) using your laptop your original copy of Windows will definitely be activated.
   **If you have a license key** then enter that when installing
   **If you don't have a key** it is not necessarily a loss as the downloaded copy will activate perfectly well **if** your original copy was activated.  You just say you don't have a key when installing.  You can check the activation occurred or not after installation by clicking the Start button > Settings > Update & Security > Activation.  If it is activated, then brilliant.  If not you will be prompted to go to the Windows Store, where you can purchase a Windows 10 license.